# TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5___default(...)(...).isotope is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use isotope.js.
I've installed it through npm but still not working.
Jquery works fine. I am using refs to refer to the dom node.
I've searched a lot but didn't find the right way.
Getting this error :
TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5___default(...)(...).isotope is not a function

My code :

```
     class Portfolio extends React.Component {

      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.portGridRef = React.createRef();
      }

    componentDidMount() {
        
        var portfolioGrid = this.portGridRef.current;

        $(portfolioGrid).isotope();
    }

    shouldComponentUpdate() {
        return false;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>
    
                <Header/>
    
                <main id="main">
    
                    <Breadcrumb currentPage="Portfolio"/>
    
                    <section id="portfolio" className="portfolio">
    
                            <div className="container">
    
                                <div className="section-title">
    
                                    <h2>Our Portfolio</h2>
    
                                </div>
    
                                <div className="row"  >
                                    <div className="col-lg-12">
                                    <ul id="portfolio-flters">
                                        <li data-filter="*" className="filter-active">All</li>
                                        <li data-filter=".filter-app">App</li>
                                        <li data-filter=".filter-card">Card</li>
                                        <li data-filter=".filter-web">Web</li>
                                    </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                        
                                <div className="row portfolio-container" ref={this.portGridRef}>
    
                                    {
                                        PortfolioData.map((currentItem, index) => {
                                           return  <PortfolioItem key={index} title={currentItem.title} category={currentItem.category} image={currentItem.image} />
                                        })
                                    }
                                    
                                </div>
                        
    
                            </div>
    
                        </section>
    
                    </main>
    
                <Footer/>
    
            </Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export default Portfolio;
```

Comment: https://isotope.metafizzy.co/extras.html#webpack did you look at the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Yatrix. He posted the link to extras page of isotope documentation.

You must include plugin like this (same thing is given in documentation) :

```
var $ = require('jquery');
var jQueryBridget = require('jquery-bridget');
var Isotope = require('isotope-layout');
```

and then

```
jQueryBridget( 'isotope', Isotope, $ );
       var portfolioIsotope =   $(this.portGridRef.current).isotope({
            layoutMode: 'fitRows'
        });
```

Comment: This jquery-bridget has some issues in IE11